# cpp std-style conversion between uint64_t array and uint8_t array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm looking for a cpp "std-style" way to access an the same static array as uint64_t array and uint8_t array, here are examples how I saw it solved in C, without bit operations:

```
union {
    uint64_t u64[16];
    uint8_t u8[128];
} array;

// array.u8[13];
```

or,

```
uint64_t u64_array[16];
uint8_t* u8_array = u64_array;
// u8_array[13];
```

Comment: C++ doesn't really do type aliasing.  You could cast the `uint64_t` array to a `unsigned char*` or `std::byte*` to walk the bytes

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a std-style solution

Comment: Type punning to or from `unsigned char` is fine. But it's better to use `std::bit_cast` which creates a copy and avoids violating **strict aliasing rule**. A read-modify-write cycle can be used along with `std::bit_cast`.

Comment: you can also use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which is the C++ way of union

Comment: @phuclv does std::variant have same memory layout properties as union?

Comment: yes, of course. The memory is shared, but there'll be a tag field like a tagged-union for more safety. Just do some research https://www.cppstories.com/2018/06/variant/

Comment: @phuclv what about std::variant<std::array<uint8_t, 128>, std::array<uint64_t, 16>>, will it work properly as union replacement?

Answer (score 0):

There really only is the way of casting to a pointer to one of the many `char`  types. If you want to mix in some `std`ishness how about this:

```
uint64_t u64_array[16];
auto raw = std::span{(uint8_t*)u64_array, 128};
```

Comment: Note that this works only if/because std::uint8_t is an alias of unsigned char which is special (along with char and std::byte)

Comment: @eerorika I don't understand your comment, what's special about unsigned char and char in this context?

Comment: The standard specifies that you can cast anything to a `char` kind of type and access the raw bit pattern. Casting to `uint16*` for example would be ill-formed for example.